# how to write test class for Batchable

Tags: unit-test, batch

```
global class operationsDeleteBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        String query = 'Select id from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<account> scope) {
        delete scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can use public instead of global and that the query can be static SOQL which is usually the better choice i.e. `return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id from Account]);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see below example. Hope it will help you.

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
private class Test_operationsDeleteBatch  {
    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        //Create Account Record
        Account account = new Account(Name = 'Testing' ,Industry = 'Association' ,Type = 'Prospect');
        insert account;

        //Test Start
        test.StartTest();

        //Batch instance
        operationsDeleteBatch batch = new operationsDeleteBatch();
        DataBase.executeBatch(batch);

        //Test stop here
        test.StopTest();

        //Assert Here

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create test class data (Record) as normal we do
2. Call your batch class between start and stop methods

   ```
   //Start Testing from here
   Test.startTest();

   //Instace of batch
   operationsDeleteBatch br = new operationsDeleteBatch();
   Database.executeBatch(br);


   //Stop Testing Here
   Test.stopTest();

   // Your asserts
   ```

The [Test.stopTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_stopTest) documentation explains that:

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected
>   by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes
>   are run synchronously.

i.e. that method call is needed to get the Batchable executed.

Comment: Nice Ans +1. Just one request. Can you please add few lines for start and stop test why we need for batch?

Comment: Hi @Vipin, Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() are the part of test methods.. You can check all methods here   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm